# How to test nested vuex actions that return promises?

Tags: testing, vue.js, promise, sinon, vuex

Here is the code from my component an the current test I have:

```
// component script
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'foo',
  mounted () {
    this.firstMethod()
      .then(() => {
        this.secondMethod()
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.thirdMethod()
      })
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      'firstMethod',
      'secondMethod',
      'thirdMethod'
    ])
  }
}

// test
import { shallow, createLocalVue } from 'vue-test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Foo from '../Foo.vue'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuex)

describe('Foo.vue', () => {
  let actions
  let store
  let wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    actions = {
      firstMethod: sinon.stub().resolves(),
      secondMethod: sinon.stub().resolves(),
      thirdMethod: sinon.stub(),
    }

    store = new Vuex.Store({
      actions
    })

    wrapper = shallow(Foo, { store, localVue })
  })

  it.only('calls store actions when mounted', () => {
    expect(actions.firstMethod.called).toBe(true) // succeedes
    expect(actions.secondMethod.called).toBe(true) // fails
    expect(actions.thirdMethod.called).toBe(true) // fails
  })
})
```

I was expecting all three `expects` to succeed, since I understand that the `.resolves()` method makes the `stub` to return a resolved promise, and that would in turn trigger the next call under the `then` method on the component. But its not.

How should I test that the Vuex actions are indeed called?

I'm open to the idea of multiple tests instead of just one, if that makes sense. Or even to refactor the 3 calls to something else, as long as they are called in that order when successful.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand, you aren't testing whether the actions runs in sequential order, but you are testing actions itself whether they're returning the promises?

Comment: Sortof, I'm just trying to validate that they are being called when the component mounts. The fact that they are called in order, needn't concern the test, since its fixed by the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I changed the structure of my component mount method, but the test also works with the original code.

Here is the updated component with the test.

```
// component script
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'foo',
  mounted () {
    this.mount()
  },
  methods: {
    async mount () {
      await this.firstMethod()
      await this.secondMethod()
      await this.thirdMethod()
    },
    ...mapActions([
      'firstMethod',
      'secondMethod',
      'thirdMethod'
    ])
  }
}

// test
import { shallow, createLocalVue } from 'vue-test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Foo from '../Foo.vue'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuex)

describe('Foo.vue', () => {
  let actions
  let store
  let wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    actions = {
      firstMethod: sinon.stub().resolves(),
      secondMethod: sinon.stub().resolves(),
      thirdMethod: sinon.stub().resolves()
    }

    store = new Vuex.Store({
      actions
    })

    wrapper = shallow(Foo, { store, localVue })
  })

  it('calls store actions when mounted', async () => {
    await expect(actions.firstMethod.called).toBe(true)
    await expect(actions.secondMethod.called).toBe(true)
    await expect(actions.thirdMethod.called).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Hmm. These changes didn't make a positive difference for me (it still failed on the second assertion). Also, `expect(...).toBe(...)` returns `undefined`, so `await expect(...).toBe(...)` is equivalent to `await undefined`, which effectively resolves immediately. Was the intention to wait for `firstMethod`, `secondMethod`, and `thirdMethod` to resolve?

Comment: The intention is to only check that the methods on the store are called.
The test does positively work for me now, since commenting the method calls on the component, or toggling the `.toBe()` make the test fail as expected.
In understand however, that the test is super coupled to the implementation, since it needs to be written in that order specifically.
To be honest, I don't really know why its working either, only that by mostly trial and error, I ended up with that test and it worked. A little ashamed, but at least with test coverage. :S

Comment: I'm questioning the intention of the `await`s, as they're apparently unnecessary.

Comment: @tony19 well... if I take them out, the test stops working. It honestly feels like black magic to me now... but I'll try to come up with a better explanation in due time. For now, however, it is good enough.